# Interpretation of special shell variables in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I'm a docker newbie and I'm learning how to write Dockerfile.
I've been experimenting with different ways of writing RUN instructions, and I've come across some behavior that I don't understand why, so I'd like to know about it.

When I built and run the following Dockerfile.v1, the sample_file exists in the sample_dir. This is as expected.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir sample_dir && cd sample_dir && touch sample_file
```

Then, I decided to use shell variables for general purpose writing, I created the following Dockerfile.v2 and RUN.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir sample_dir && cd $_ && touch sample_file
```

Then, sample_file was created in /root, which is not what I expected.
Since the sample_dir itself was created in /, I assume WORKING DIRECTORY is /.

Why was it created in the root user's home directory? How was $_ interpreted?

```
❯ docker run -it --rm 1ce bash                                                                          2023/09/17 18:01:16
root@2ce4010e4613:/# 
root@2ce4010e4613:/# ll
total 60
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Sep 17 09:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Sep 17 09:01 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Sep 17 09:01 .dockerenv*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Aug 16 02:25 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 18  2022 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  360 Sep 17 09:01 dev/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Sep 17 09:01 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 18  2022 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Aug 16 02:25 lib -> usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 02:25 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 02:25 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 02:25 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 212 root root    0 Sep 17 09:01 proc/
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Sep 17 07:39 root/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Aug 16 04:54 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Sep 17 07:39 sample_dir/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Aug 16 02:25 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 02:25 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Sep 17 09:01 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4096 Aug 16 04:52 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root 4096 Aug 16 02:25 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root 4096 Aug 16 04:52 var/
root@2ce4010e4613:/# ll /root/
total 16
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Sep 17 07:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Sep 17 09:01 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3106 Oct 15  2021 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 Jul  9  2019 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 17 07:39 sample_file
root@2ce4010e4613:/#
```

I know I can avoid this behavior by not using $_ or by using WORKDIR instruction, but I just want to know why this is happening.

I thought it might be because the default is /bin/sh, so I specified bash in SHELL INSTRUCTION as shown below, but there was no change.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir sample_dir && cd $_ && touch sample_file
SHELL [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

My environment

```
❯ docker --version                                                                                                                                                                                      2023/09/19 21:38:37
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996

❯ sw_vers                                                                                                                                                                                               2023/09/19 21:42:27
ProductName:            macOS
ProductVersion:         13.5.2
BuildVersion:           22G91
```

detailed info

```
❯ docker build -f ./Dockerfile_old .                                                                    2023/10/03 18:13:48
[+] Building 0.2s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                       docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile_old                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 140B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                       0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                         0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN mkdir sample_dir && cd $_ && touch sample_file                                                           0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:3f2dc4ad66693b6306ee812371b79e6a2984a18e6590509be9a98108a235f7ff                           0.0s

❯ docker history --no-trunc 3f2                                                                         2023/10/03 18:15:25
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED          CREATED BY                                                                                          SIZE      COMMENT
sha256:3f2dc4ad66693b6306ee812371b79e6a2984a18e6590509be9a98108a235f7ff   37 seconds ago   RUN /bin/sh -c mkdir sample_dir && cd $_ && touch sample_file # buildkit                            0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 7 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]                                                                0B        
<missing>                                                                 7 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:8540670760767f19eaf101fbce1da1881a2f24a7d65da6abdedc644b8fb00463 in /    69.2MB    
<missing>                                                                 7 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.opencontainers.image.version=22.04                                     0B        
<missing>                                                                 7 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu                                   0B        
<missing>                                                                 7 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG LAUNCHPAD_BUILD_ARCH                                                         0B        
<missing>                                                                 7 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG RELEASE                                                                      0B        

❯ docker images | grep ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2023/10/03 18:16:23
ubuntu                  latest    bf9e5b7213b4   7 days ago      69.2MB
```

Comment: I tried this and the result is same as you. I also want to know the real reason. It seems that $_ is empty, so it executes the comamand "cd" directly, then the working directory is changed to /root. That's why the sample_file is created in the /root folder.

Comment: By the way, you can use the command "docker build -t test --progress=plain --no-cache  ." to see the output of command when building the docker image.

Comment: @boyal Thanks, I didn't now that option in build command! I tried it but I couldn't get anything new in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_` only really makes sense in interactive Bash. A more standard and portable solution is to use a regular variable.

```
RUN d=sample_dir && mkdir "$d" && cd "$d" && touch sample_file
```

... though of course, the `cd` is pretty much useless here.

```
RUN d=sample_dir && mkdir "$d" && touch "$d"/sample_file
```

Anyway, your attempt to set `SHELL` is wrong. You want

```
SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
```

Without the `-c`, your `RUN` statements would be interpreted as names of shell script files to try to execute.

Of course, when `$_` is empty, `cd $_` expands to just `cd` which changes to the current user's home directory.

Comment: > $_ only really makes sense in interactive Bash.
Can you explain a bit more about this? I could'nt find documentation to support this.

Comment: I don't mean it doesn't work in noninteractive Bash, just that it's clunky and obscure, and there are better and more portable idioms you should probably prefer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and getting back to me. I understand it's more valuable to use regular variables than my attempt. 
However my question is still unanswered and I'm bafflIed. I modified my SHELL instruction to `SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]` and the result was the same.

Comment: It seems I figured out why. The default SHELL is `SHELL [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]`, so If I put `RUN mkdir sample_dir && cd $_ && touch sample_file` instruction, then it is executed like `/bin/sh -c " mkdir sample_dir && cd $_ && touch sample_file"`. It means the `$_` specifies the arguments that was executed before the `/bin/sh -c " ... ` command.

Comment: I am unable to repro that. With `FROM ubuntu:latest` `SHELL ["bash", "-c"]` `RUN echo hello && echo $_ >file` I see `hello` when I build and then run the image and `cat file`

Comment: Thanks. In my environment, the result of `cat file` was null. Can it be because of docker version?

Comment: I have exactly the same Docker version.

Comment: Can it be a bug then? I’m not sure.

Comment: Theoretically it could be something in the image. Which `ubuntu:latest` exactly? If you haven't pulled it recently, you probably still have an older version. (But I doubt it explains this problem.)

Comment: I pulled ubuntu:latest again. And I added some more information on this build. The SHA of the ubuntu image I'm using is now 3f2dc4ad66693b6306ee812371b79e6a2984a18e6590509be9a98108a235f7ff. And the result was the same.

Comment: The trace reveals that you are running `sh`, not Bash. Voting to close as unreproducible. I will remind you to please read the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX shell specification only defines a limited set of [Special Parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), `$@`, `$*`, `$#`, `$?`, `$-`, `$$`, `$!`, and `$0`.  The default shell is a POSIX-compliant shell and not GNU bash (see for example [this question](/q/20635472)) so other shell-specific extensions aren't available.  `$_` isn't one of the standard-defined special parameters, so it expands to an empty string.  Since you haven't quoted the variable expansion either, the argument to `cd` just gets lost, and that's how you wind up in `/root`.

In a Docker context more specifically, also remember that each `RUN` line starts a new shell in a new container, and parts of the shell context that change are lost.  In particular `RUN cd` won't have a persistent effect.    I might suggest using the Dockerfile `WORKDIR` directive to change directories

```sh
WORKDIR /sample_dir
RUN touch sample_file
```

which will also create the directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The OP does mention they tried to set `SHELL`, though they are not divulging what exactly they tried. Perhaps they used incorrect syntax or put the instruction in the wrong place.

Comment: @david-maze
Thanks. But the default shell seems to be dash or bash and I could use $_ as shown below:

```
# echo $0
sh
# echo $_
sh
# which sh
/usr/bin/sh
# ls -l /usr/bin/sh                      
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 23  2022 /usr/bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: @tripleee I added the dockerfile that I used SHELL instruction to use bash.

Comment: Thanks for including it. As it turns out, this reinforces why we insist on including exactly the code you tried. I have updated my answer.